# How to change GIMP print size with script-fu

Tags: gimp, script-fu, python-fu

I am using GIMP 2.10.24. I have some image and I need to change Print Size Width to 21mm and Height to 30mm.
I can do that with Set Image Print Resolution Dialog (Menu->Image->Print Size):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZTjg.png)

But there is my question: how could I do that using script-fu or python-fu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print size, size in pixels, and print definition are completely related:

```
print size = size in pixels ÷ print definition
```

So to change the image print definition you use

In Python:

```py
pdb.gimp_image_set_resolution(image, xresolution, yresolution)
```

In Script-fu:

```lisp
(gimp-image-set-resolution image xresolution yresolution)
```

In both case the X/Y resolutions are in dots per inch.

However if you are using Gimp just for this creating a Gimp script is overkill (the learning curve is quite steep). If the image is in a common format (JPEG, PNG, TIFF) the print definition is part of the image metadata (JPEG header, or EXIF data) and can be changed directly without decoding/reencoding the image using CLI utilities. For instance with ExifTool:

```
exiftool ${your_image} -xResolution=321 -yResolution=321
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. According to this post I have solved my problem like that:
  
    (let* (
  (imageWidth (car (gimp-image-width image)))
  (imageHeight (car (gimp-image-height image)))
  (xresolution (/ imageWidth (/ 21 25.4)))
  (yresolution (/ imageHeight (/ 30 25.4)))
  )
   (gimp-image-set-resolution image xresolution yresolution)
    )

Comment: Possibly... I don't use script-fu. In python that would be a quite simple: `pdb.gimp_image_set_resolution(image, image.width/printWidth,image.height/printHeight)`. But seriously unless the script does something else that only exists in Gimp, you are much better off using ExifTool in a shell script (100x faster, bith in developement for you and in execution)

Comment: Of course, it's just part of a larger script. I was just asking about something I stuck on